# Is it possible to transmit Longitude and Latitude via RF433MHz?

Tags: arduino-uno, sensors, xbee, android, map

I want to make a drone project, and to that I will use arduino as the platform. My plane is to use a Play Station controller to control the Drone in the air. In addition to that I want to connect a GPS-module. My question goes, is it possible to transmit the longitude and latitude from the GPS via the RF 433MHz to the receiver? When received the longitude and latitude how can I transmit them further to the Smartphone and display the data on google maps? I suggest it could be possible through the Xbee, but I am not sure.

I would like if someone can confirm my idea, if not bring me a better way to do that.

In the image below, you can see the diagram of my design.

[image]

Comment: Welcome AdiT! I've seen you posted [the same question](http://electronics.stackexchange.com/q/108487/29792) at EE.SE. I would like to let you know that cross-posting across SE sites is not generally a good idea. See [this post](http://meta.stackexchange.com/a/64069) for more details.

Comment: @Ricardo Okay I'm sorry, I didn't know it :)

Comment: That's ok. It's just a minor sin :D I just really wanted to let you know. Let's just wait for some answers.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your design suffers several redundancies that should be fixed. First of all, you have an Xbee (only one, not a pair) *and* a a 433 MHz transmitter/receiver combo. **Why not just add another Xbee to the drone and remove the RF combo?** That would save a little battery life for the receiver end, and a lot of your time. You'll also get two way communication with error checking. Although an Xbee would increase your project size a *little*, if you manually wired the Xbee instead of a shield (3.3V), it would save a lot of space.

As some people point out, Bluetooth is a viable option that's fairly small and low cost. However, it would suffer shorter ranges and it would need a special configuration on the host side for a BT stack.

Comment: I want to use RF because of I want a longer range. Therefore I'm not using WiFi. I don't understand what do you mean with this "if you manually wired it (3.3V)"? What should I manually wired?

Comment: @AdiT Edited post a bit. I meant manually wiring the Xbee module as opposed to a shield to save space/reduce weight. By the way, Xbee *is* RF. You can get several different distance ranges of Xbee to suit your needs.

Answer (score 2):

If you are using Xbee modules in your project, why add 433MHz RF, just for the sole purpose of transmitting the location?  With the 433Mhz, you will have to implement error-correction yourself.

Comment: You have a point. How else is it possible to transmit the data to smartphone?

Comment: @AdiT bluetooth for one